# 6x6 Covariance Matrix Conversion from ENU to ECEF

Tags: java, math, matrix, covariance, coordinate-transformation

I am currently working with a RADAR that outputs a 6x6 covariance matrix with every track in the following format:

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Col5 | Col6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| (EP)(EP) | (EP)(NP) | (EP)(UP) | (EP)(EV) | (EP)(NV) | (EP)(UV) |
| (NP)(EP) | (NP)(NP) | (NP)(UP) | (NP)(EV) | (NP)(NV) | (NP)(UV) |
| (UP)(EP) | (UP)(NP) | (UP)(UP) | (UP)(EV) | (UP)(NV) | (UP)(UV) |
| (EV)(EP) | (EV)(NP) | (EV)(UP) | (EV)(EV) | (EV)(NV) | (EV)(UV) |
| (NV)(EP) | (NV)(NP) | (NV)(UP) | (NV)(EV) | (NV)(NV) | (NV)(UV) |
| (UV)(EP) | (UV)(NP) | (UV)(UP) | (UV)(EV) | (UV)(NV) | (UV)(UV) |

Where, **EP = East Postion, NP = North Postion,UP = Up Position, EV = East Velocity, NV = North Velocity, and UV = UP Velocity. Let [EP][EP]=Cov(EP,EP)=Var(EP) and so on**

In my research I have found this: https://gssc.esa.int/navipedia/index.php/Transformations_between_ECEF_and_ENU_coordinates

This gives exactly what I need for a 3x3 ENU to ECEF **position only** covariance transformation. My first assumption is that I would simply duplicate the Rotational Matrix **(R)** like so:
[image: 6x6 Rotational Matrix]

Where **lambda = longitude of the radar and phi = latitude of radar**.

Then from this paper: https://www.ngs.noaa.gov/CORS/Articles/SolerChin1985.pdf
[image]

Where Summation WGS72 is actually just the ENU 6x6 covariance matrix I am receiving.

Implementing in Java I am getting the following:

```
    public static void enu2ecefCov(GMatrix ecefCov, GMatrix enuCov, LLA refLLA) {
        GMatrix R = new GMatrix(6, 6);
        GMatrix Rt = new GMatrix(6, 6);
        GMatrix tmp = new GMatrix(6, 6);

        createRotationMatrixV3(R, refLLA);

        Rt.transpose(R);
        tmp.mul(enuCov, R);
        ecefCov.mul(Rt, tmp);

    }
```

However, the matrix I am outputting doesn't look correct as I am seeing the same values multiple times whereas the original doesn't have the same values at all besides symmetric corresponding blocks. Am I doing this correctly?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding what you are trying to do here. Do you have the 6 ENU values EP, NP, UP, EV, NV, UV? In your covariance matrix, is each element a product of two of these? Are you trying to create a similar covariance matrix but in ECEF coordinates?

Comment: I am getting the 6x6 variance-covariance ENU matrix from the RADAR and I am trying to transform it into a 6x6 variance-covariance in ECEF. With that said, I have all of the variances and covariances for all elements of the ENU matrix. I am just not sure what the Rotational Matrix should look like. Does that make sense?

Comment: @SimonGoater Also, each element is not the product of the two. The diagonals are the variances and all other elements are the covariances. [EP][EP]=Cov(EP,EP)=Variance(EP)=<some floating point value>m^2, [EP][NP]=Cov(EP,NP)=<some floating point value>m^2, and so on. I am actually receiving floating point values for each element in the ENU matrix where the matrix is symmetric(i.e (col,row)=(row,col)).

Comment: Try to zero out the upper right and lower left blocks (the off-diagonal blocks) in your rotation matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two fixes to make:

1. Update your rotation matrix to have zeros in the off-diagonal blocks.
2. Calculate C' = RCR<sup>T</sup>, where C' is the ECEF covariance matrix and C is ENU covariance matrix, and R is the rotation matrix from ENU to ECEF for your position-velocity combination.

**Reasoning for Fix #1**

The position and velocity are like two different data points to be rotated and the rotation matrix should reflect their independence.  To do that, take your original 3x3 rotation matrix for ENU -> ECEF:

```
R = | -sin(λ), -cos(λ)*sin(φ), cos(λ)*cos(φ) | 
    |  cos(λ), -sin(λ)*sin(φ), sin(λ)*cos(φ) |
    |       0,         cos(φ),        sin(φ) |
```

And use it to build a 6x6 rotation matrix (let '0' = 3x3 matrix of 0s)

```
R = |R 0|
    |0 R|
```

Symbolic calculation of a rotation:

```
R = | R11 R12 R13   0   0   0 |
    | R21 R22 R23   0   0   0 |
    | R31 R32 R33   0   0   0 | 
    |   0   0   0 R11 R12 R13 |
    |   0   0   0 R21 R22 R23 |
    |   0   0   0 R31 R32 R33 |

x = | e1 |
    | n1 |
    | u1 |
    | e2 |
    | n2 |
    | u2 |

x' = Rx = | R11*e1 + R12*n1 + R13*u1 +   0*e2 +   0*n2 +   0*u2 |
          | R21*e1 + R22*n1 + R23*u1 +   0*e2 +   0*n2 +   0*u2 |
          | R31*e1 + R32*n1 + R33*u1 +   0*e2 +   0*n2 +   0*u2 |
          |   0*e1 +   0*n1 +   0*u1 + R11*e2 + R12*n2 + R13*u2 |
          |   0*e1 +   0*n1 +   0*u1 + R21*e2 + R22*n2 + R23*u2 |
          |   0*e1 +   0*n1 +   0*u1 + R31*e2 + R32*n2 + R33*u2 |
```

The result is a 6x1 vector that is basically the stacking of one independently rotated (e,n,u) on top of another.

**Reasoning for Fix #2**

```
let X = | EP_1  EP_2 .. EP_n|  (i.e. a set of measurements)
        | NP_1  NP_2 .. NP_n|
        | UP_1  UP_2 .. UP_n|
        | EV_1  EV_2 .. EV_n|
        | NV_1  NV_2 .. NV_n|
        | UV_1  UV_2 .. UV_n|

let Xt = tranpose(X)
let C = variance-covariance matrix

C = E(XXt) - E(X)E(Xt)

let X' = RX = rotated measurements
let C' = variance-covariance matrix of rotated measurements

C' = E(X'X't) - E(X')E(X't)
   = E(RXXtRt) - E(RX)E(XtRt)     remember (AB)t = BtAt
   = RE(XXt)Rt - RE(X)E(Xt)Rt
   = R(E(XXt) - E(X)E(Xt))Rt
C' = RCRt
```

That shows that when a set of measurements is rotated, its original variance-covariance matrix can be transformed into the new coordinate system as a function of the rotation matrix.

Answer (score -1):

I *think* I have done what you are looking for.. So basically it seems that there may be an issue with the implementation of the `createRotationMatrixV3` function or with the input ENU covariance matrix. I took a little bit of time to mess around with the sin and cos Math functions to try and do it manually.

Here is the code that I ended up with: https://codecatch.net/post/008da886-fa1a-4995-a024-f58d883e0504

Comment: While it is perfectly fine to link to codecatch.net, it would be good if you included the code directly in your answer here as well (with formatting), because if the other service is shut down or unreachable for whatever reason, your answer will be useless without the code.

Comment: Yes please to @cyberbrain's comment - could you edit the post, Austin?